# Nodejs - Rest api call with option --data from a file

Tags: node.js, rest, curl

I am making rest api calls from a nodejs application.

My curl calls looks like this:

```
curl -X PUT -iv -H "Authorization: bearer <token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Spark-Service-Instance: <spark-instance>" --data "@pipeline.json" -k https://<url>
```

I want to have a similar call in Nodejs. I am unable to understand how to have the data sent which is in a json file which in curl call was `--data "@pipeline.json".`

My Nodejs code looks like this:

```
var token = req.body.mlToken;
var urlToHit = req.body.url;
var SPARKINSTANCE = req.body.sparkInstance;
var b = "bearer ";
var auth = b.concat(token); 


var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': auth,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-Spark-Service-Instance': SPARKINSTANCE
}

var options= {
    url: urlToHit,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: headers
}

console.log(urlToHit);
request(options, callback);
function callback(error, response, body) {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the [**request**](https://github.com/request/request) library to **pipe** the request as so:

```
var fs = require('fs');     
var options= {
    url: urlToHit,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: headers
}

fs.createReadStream('./pipeline.json')
  .pipe(request.put(options, callback))
```

---

Or, using plain Node.js, read the **file in to memory asynchronously** and the once loaded, make a put request like this:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
// Will need this for determining 'Content-Length' later
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer   

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': auth,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-Spark-Service-Instance': SPARKINSTANCE
}

var options= {
    host: urlToHit,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: headers
}

// After readFile has read the whole file into memory, send request
fs.readFile('./pipeline.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  sendRequest(options, data, callback);
});

function sendRequest (options, postData, callback) {  
  var req = http.request(options, callback);

  // Set content length (RFC 2616 4.3)
  options.headers['Content-Length'] = Buffer.byteLength(postData)

  // Or other way to handle error
  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
  });

  // write data to request body
  req.write(postData);
  req.end();
}
```

Comment: Will this also require something like : const fs = require('fs');

Comment: Can you please also change the filepath as without "." .It might confuse someone! fs.createReadStream('/pipeline.json'). Thanks for the help